# Serilog does not log for Debug logging

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, serilog

I am using Serilog with asp.net core 3.1.5

```
Func<LogEvent, bool> debugInfoRangeFilter = e => e.Level == LogEventLevel.Debug || e.Level == LogEventLevel.Information;

Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .MinimumLevel.Verbose()
    .WriteTo.Logger(c => c.Filter.ByIncludingOnly(debugInfoRangeFilter)
        .WriteTo.Async(a =>
        {
            a.File($"{AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory}\\Logs\\log.txt",
                rollOnFileSizeLimit: true,
                retainedFileCountLimit: 10,
                fileSizeLimitBytes: 10 * 1024 * 1024); // 10MB
        }))
    .WriteTo.Logger(c => c.Filter.ByExcluding(debugInfoRangeFilter)
        .WriteTo.Async(a =>
        {
            a.File($"{AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory}\\Logs\\error.txt",
                rollOnFileSizeLimit: true,
                retainedFileCountLimit: 10,
                fileSizeLimitBytes: 10 * 1024 * 1024); // 10MB
        }))
    .CreateLogger();
```

The problem I have is that Debug log entries are not written to the log.txt file. I cant see them anywhere whereas all other levels are successfully written.

I call this

```
 logger.LogDebug("Log Debug");
 logger.LogInformation("Log Info");
```

`Log Info` is written to the log.txt `Log.Debug` is not there.
Anyone knows what am I doing wrong?

Update #1:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog" Version="2.9.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Extensions.Logging" Version="3.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Settings.Configuration" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Async" Version="1.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.File" Version="4.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Could you please tell which Serilog version you have used now? Could you please post 
all the related serilog package version.

Comment: @BrandoZhang I have updated my initial post with the versions

Comment: Could you please tell me which mode you have used when you run your application? Release or debug?

Comment: @BrandoZhang I have used both and the problem occurs in both

Comment: Could you please tell me when you use  logger.LogDebug("Log Debug");
 logger.LogInformation("Log Info");? In controller action or directly after the create logger? I have directly used             `Log.Logger.Debug("Log Debug");
            Log.Logger.Information("Log Info");` and it works well.

Comment: @BrandoZhang I am using them throughout the system. e.g on a service I inject the ILogger<T>. I m calling them in exactly the same place. Info works, debug does not work

Comment: I suggest you could try to modify the `appsettings.Development.json` log level to debug and try again.

Comment: @BrandoZhang I dont have any settings in my appsettings related to logging. Settings are hardcoded (check initial post)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217726/discussion-between-brando-zhang-and-pantonis).

Comment: @pantonis - Please post an answer it you found one with your chat with BrandoZhang